# Getting MessagingException in Mulesoft

Tags: dataweave

I am getting this weird exception while debugging the mule code in Anypoint studio. Error occurs when 'Transform Message' message processor is getting executed.

org.mule.api.MessagingException: com/mulesoft/flatfile/schema/FlatFileParserBase (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError).

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was problem with Schema or any FFD you are using.or You are not locating correct ffd for this.

Can you please attached Dwl code.

Thanks,

Manish Yadav